# javascript array filter not working good with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, typescript, next.js

hi everyone I'm trying to delete an element from my array which is a useState array. I have index of the element that I want to delete and I'm trying to do this like:

```
const newArray = myArray.filter((item:any, index:number) =>
          return index !== props.userGivenIndex)

          setmyArray(newArray)
```

my code is working but sometimes its deleting random elements which is not satisfying the given conditions. what am I doing wrong here??

I have tried wraping the function in useCallback as well as for memorizing the value I tried useMemo too but neither if them worked.

Comment: What is `myArray`? For what inputs is it deleting random elements?

Comment: do you use `key` attribute when you render the array? If yes, then do you use `index` as the key?

Comment: Yes I used key={index} @wonderflame

Comment: const [myArray, setmyArray] = useState([]); @mykaf, onclick of a button I'm passing a prop which is desired index of element that should delete

Comment: What is the actual array for `myArray`?

Comment: it is positions in x,y,z axes like [[1,-1.0],[0,-5,1],[1,-6,2],[0,0,0]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if you want to remove the item under a specific index, you have to write:

```
myArray.filter((item:any, index:number) =>
  index !== props.userGivenIndex
);
```

However, it's not the only problem. Elements are removed randomly because, as you mentioned, you use the index as a `key` attribute when you render the array.

The [key](https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists#keeping-list-items-in-order-with-key) attribute is necessary for React to identify which elements were modified, deleted, and added to render the list correctly. In your case, when you delete an item in the middle of the array, the items after that index are shifted to the left, which means their indexes have been changed, and it doesn't allow React to do its job. If you remove the last element, you won't see any bugs since there is no shifting because there are no elements after the removed one. However, if you remove the first one, all other elements will shift to the left, which may lead to really unexpected behavior.

To prevent such issues, please consider using something else for `key`, specifically related to the given element. You can generate a random `id` for elements as a last resort.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you so much @wonderflame , I was stuck at this for so long. I tried deleting elements from last to first and guess what all of it deleted without any random deletions between them. So i think now I need to use something else as key, I'm thinking of using uuid.

Comment: I changed they key prop with some other generated ids but why am I still seeing the same behavior as previous ?? still some elements deleting randomly ::::((((( @wonderflame

Comment: can you share the updated code?

Comment: Its the same all I did is change the key prop from key={index} to key={currentElement[0]}. Every element has unique values so I think it should have worked....

Comment: You mentioned that they are the coordinates, which are numbers. And they might be the same. If you are sure there are no identical 3d points in your array, then you can try to go with `currentElement.join(',')`

Comment: tried using it too but still sometimes the order is messing and I also tried uuid and nanoid but as a result all of my models re rendering every time some event is happening. Now I'm not getting how can I provide unique key to all the elements. I think somehow one or two elements are getting same ids even with currentElement.join

Comment: We could think of a solution if you could share your implementation and array. And instead of updating the id on every render, I would suggest mapping the `myArray` to contain `{id: string, coordinates: [number, number, number]}`. Run this function once (not in render) and use `currentElement.id` as a key

Comment: `setmyArray(() => {   const id =new Date().getMilliseconds() + new Date().getTime();
          return([ ...myArray, {id:id, coordinates:[props.xAxis, props.yAxis, props.zAxis]},]);
      });`  this is where my array is being created. and I'm rendering it like this : `<MyModel  key={pos.id} position={pos.coordinates} ID={ID} />` but somehow still I'm facing random deletes @wonderflame

Comment: Relying on milliseconds is not a good chpice. Several items may have the same id, since js is fast enough to execute at least two iterations. Just use id:Math.random()

Comment: getting same results,at this point I have used react-uuid,uuid genrators, shortids,but still they are just randomly deleting or deleting from highest index to 0

Comment: Please include the whole code where you `map` on the array

Comment: `{myArray.map((currentElement: any, index: any) => (
          <MyModel  key={currentElement.id} userGivenIndex={index} position=currentElement.coordinates} ID={ID} length={length / 1000} width={width / 1000} />))}`

Comment: interesting, I can't spot the error. Can you consider add a codesandbox or some other editor

Comment: yep give me a moment, will share a sandbox link

Comment: Hi @wonderflame, I've noticed one thing that the deletion is not happening randomly at all its always happening from highest index to 0th index.

Comment: Include the sandbox link I will check what happens